# Return an object in catch block within Task body

Tags: c#, exception, task

Please consider the following scenario.

I have a Task, that returns an object, lets say it's of type:

```
class A
{
string success;
}
```

Now the task's body is for example:

```
{
return new A() { success = "yes" }
}
```

The outside of this task doesn't matter, if it's continous task or anything. What's important is that on return from that task I can read this returned object by task.Result.status.

The problem I have, is that if I'd like to return the object of that kind within the try/catch block, the task.Result.status is null, and task.Result is of AggregatedException type. So for example:

```
//(Task body)
{
{
try
{
//something throwing exception
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
return new A() { success = "yes" }
}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to get that object that is returned in the catch block, when the execution returns from that task, instead of AggregatedException that I receive now.

Please, restrain yourself from the usuall forums "answers" like "why would you want it", "what's the point of it" etc. I'm not interested in answers like that.

If it can't be done and you know it for a fact (maybe the tasks when throw exceptions always return AggregatedException no matter what), then please tell me so straightforward. If it can on the other hand, I'd appriciate how I can achieve that.

Lucas

Comment: What you describe is not happening. In `ContinueWith` the task passed in has a Result with the same type of the return value of the previous task. So it should be `A` in your case. It never can be an Exception, except when the previous task actually returned an exception (return, not throw!). Furthermore, exceptions caught inside your task's body will never result in an AggregateException as the TPL never gets to see them. Conclusion: Please change your question to something that actually happens and provide a working example of what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the note Simon. I will look over my old questions I didn't check for a long time, and if I find acceptable answers to me, I will mark them as such.

Comment: You were correct Daniel. I simplify the problem in hope to find a solution quickly.

In anyway, I did find it eventually, the error of mine is explained in my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could be explained better but as I understand it this is pretyt much what you want to do and should work.

```
//(Task body)
{
    A result = null;
    try
    {
        //something that might throwing exception but could also new the result
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        result = new A() { success = "yes" }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Exceptions caught inside a Task should not propagate up to the AggregateException. If that is still happening you are doing something wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You were right that I was doing something wrong. For that, you got the check mark. Explanation below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The emotions got the best of me.

As always the problem was something I was not able to see before.

I tried to simplify my problem to find the root of the problem, that's why the code was so basic above. It turned out that Task exception handling is very complex, especialy when we deal with inner Tasks, and with Wait calls.

I was calling innerTask.Wait() method, and that method was throwing the Aggregate exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx

Even though the innerTask execution was running, and it was returing the object, the outer task was handling the exception prior to that.

Once I realised that, the fix was very simple and easy.